# Largest path of non-repeating edges in undirected graph

Tags: eulerian-paths

Given an undirected graph, I want to find the largest path of non-repeating edges (can repeat vertices). I know such a path that uses all edges is known as Euler path, and can be found in O(E), where E is the number of edges. What if the graph doesn't have an Euler path, how can one find the largest path of this kind?

Comment: The decision version of this problem is NP-complete as shown [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/20685).

Comment: I read it, but there are a few things I didn't get, maybe you can help. He uses Hamiltonian path with max degree 3, but then assumes the graph would have a vertex with degree 2. Also, it's not obvious to me why being NP-complete for degree up to 3, would mean it's NP-complete for degree k > 3 (because when he adds 2 edges, the degree goes above 3)

Comment: @Powereleven The assumptions are restrictive. That is, they are showing that *even in the case* of degree 3, it is hard. So if you had a solution that solved the general case, you could surely solve the degree-3 version as well. If you have difficulty understanding NP-hardness reductions, perhaps you should be asking a specific question about that specific proof instead of this general question (which JohnL.'s response pretty much fully answers)